# C write and read single character

Tags: c, stream

I'm currently working with processes, and encountered a problem while reading and writing char to a file.

The idea is we have couple of processes which should **read an integer** from file, **increment it** and **write** back. Here is my attempt: (i wont include error checking)

```
...
char n;
char buff[5];
int number;
...
read(my_desc, &n, 1);
number = (int)n;
number++;
sprintf(buff, "%4d", number);
write(my_desc, buff, sizeof(buff));
...
```

The file is just plain

> 0

But the output seems to be not correct (almost always garbage).

I already read write and read manuals but im clueless. I've checked some topics on read and write functions here on stack overflow, but most of them either don't work for me or i struggle with implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This also allows other people to easily test your program, by using copy&paste

Comment: What is the return value of the function `read`?

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, it is 1.

Comment: I suggest that you use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, to ensure that no buffer overflow is occurring.

Comment: It looks like you are reading a single char and writing a string.  Note that without a seek, the write will happen at a different place than the read.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have tried snprintf too, but it also dosen't give proper output (incremented integer).

Comment: @stark Hi, thank you for your contribution. What would be a proper implementation of writing a single integer to a file ?

Comment: It seems that you are reading a single character, taking the [ASCII code](https://asciichart.com/) of that character and converting that number to a 4-character string, and then writing those 4 characters and the terminating null character back to the file. In other words, you are reading 1 character from the file and writing 5 characters to the file. Is that intended?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel No it is not. I thought i have to use (at least) 4 byte array for integer type. My intention is to read one char, convert it to integer, incerement and write this incremented value back to the file.

Comment: Is your file a text file, which contains the character `'0'`, which is the value `48` in ASCII? Or is the file in binary format, so that it actually contains a single byte with the value `0`? In other words, were you using a text editor or a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) to create the contents of the file?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have used nvim (so i guess it is a basic text editor) and my file is called "file.txt"

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `sprintf` and `write` instead of simply `fprintf`?

Comment: Unfortunately it is my homework and i have to use ```write``` and ```read```. I have tried to do it the whole day, and end up here seeking for some advice. I appreciate your answers.

Comment: How should your program behave if the text `47` is written in the file? Should your program read both characters `4` and `7`, and write the characters `4` and `8` back? Or should it only read the `4` and write a `5` back? And where should these characters be written? Should the original characters be overwritten?

Comment: It should read ```4``` ```7``` and write  ```4``` ```8```  back.

Comment: In that case, the line `read(my_desc, &n, 1);` is wrong, as you should attempt to read as many characters as possible (i.e. the full length of the file), instead of only attempting to read a single character.

Comment: That is true. However it does not work even for numbers from 0-9, so i thought i had to figure out how to incerement signle character first.

Comment: The problem is that you are confusing the text and binary representation of numbers. I am writing a proper answer, which will take me a few minutes.

Comment: What should happen if your program reads `9` `9` from the file? Should it overwrite the file with the 3 characters `1` `0` `0`, increasing the length of the file?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I don't think i will need values exceeding 99. However i think it should go to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are reading a single character, taking the [ASCII code](https://asciichart.com/) of that character and converting that number to a 4-character string, and then writing those 4 characters and the terminating null character back to the file.

According to the information that you provided in the comments section, this is not intended. If I understand you correctly, you rather want to

1. read the entire file as a string,
2. convert that string to a number,
3. increment that number,
4. convert that number back to a string and
5. overwrite the entire file with that string.

Step #1 can be accomplished with the function [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html). However, you should read in the whole file instead of only a single character.

Step #2 can be accomplished by using the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Step #3 is trivial.

Step #4 can be accomplished using the function [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Step #5 can be accomplished by rewinding the file using the function [`lseek`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html), and then using the function [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html).

I am assuming that the number represented in the file is in the respresentable range of a `long int`, which is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `+9,223,372,036,854,775,807` on most POSIX platforms. This means that the length of the string can be up to 19 characters, 20 including the terminating null character. That is why I am using a buffer size of `20`.

```
char buffer[20], *p;
ssize_t bytes_read;
long num;

bytes_read = read( my_desc, buffer, (sizeof buffer) - 1 );

if ( bytes_read <= 0 )
{
    //TODO: handle input error
}

//add null terminating character to string
buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';

//attempt to convert the string to a number
num = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );

//check for conversion error
if ( p == buffer )
{
    //TODO: handle conversion error
}

//increment the number
num++;

//write incremented number to buffer
snprintf( buffer, sizeof buffer, "%ld", num );

//rewind file
lseek( my_desc, 0, SEEK_SET );

//write buffer to file
write( my_desc, buffer, strlen(buffer) );
```

Note that I have not tested this code.

Also note that this program assumes that the input file does not contain any leading zeros. If the file contains the text string `"003"`, then this program will overwrite the first character with a `4`, but leave the remaining characters in the file intact. If this is an issue, then you will have to add a call to [`ftruncate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html) to truncate the file.

Comment: This is exactly what i've tried to achieve. Thank you Mr Wenzel.